# Getting all visible elements using MooTools

Tags: javascript, mootools, css-selectors

I am moving from jQuery to MooTools (for the fun..) and I have this line of code :

```
$subMenus = $headMenu.find('li ul.sub_menu:visible');
```

How I can write this in mootools?
I know that I can use getElements but How I can check for visible ul?(I am using this(:visible) selector a lot).

### Edit -

I implemented my own function :

```
  function findVisibleElements(elementsCollection){
    var returnArray = [];
    elementsCollection.each(function(el){
      if(el.getStyle('display') === 'block'){
        returnArray.push(el);
      }
    });

    return returnArray;
  }
```

And what i want is to slide up all the visible sub menu, this is what I wrote :

```
// Sliding up the visible sub menus 
if( visibleSubMenus.length > 0 ){
  visibleSubMenus.each(function(el){
      var slider = new Fx.Slide(el, {duration: 2000});
      slider.slideOut();
  });
}
```

Why my code isn`t working?My function is working, and the problem is with the Fx.Slide.
I added mootools more with Fx.Slide.

Comment: Accept some awnsers on your last 5 questions, makes people want to help you more.

Comment: we use mootools for everything on the current product my company develops. I actually recommend future people don't make this switch -- jquery is a centerpiece for a lot of really great up and coming libraries, and mootools doesn't do error handling as elegantly as jquery

Comment: My team also uses MooTools for just about everything and, contrary to Kristian, I recommend people **DO** make the switch... if they're looking for all the power and flexibility of JQuery with a different more familiar JavaScript-y syntax. Otherwise, like most other JS frameworks, they're essentially the same. It's a personal preference. Error handling in MooTools is elegant, IMO (e.g. if something screws up, let me know. If I don't want to deal with it, I'll catch the exception). tl;dr: YMMV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just extend the selector functionality - it's MooTools!

```
$extend(Selectors.Pseudo, {
    visible: function() {
        if (this.getStyle('visibility') != 'hidden' && this.isVisible() && this.isDisplayed()) {
            return this;
        }
    }
});
```

After that just do the usual `$$('div:visible')` which will return the elements that are visible.

Check out the example I've created: http://www.jsfiddle.net/oskar/zwFeV/

Comment: Thanks! why this line of code don`t work?
var slider = new Fx.Slide(visibleSubMenus, {duration: 2000});

Comment: Probably because `visibleSubMenus` is a collection of elements, and Fx.Slide takes a single element as the first value.  Check out the example URL again (I've updated it) - http://www.jsfiddle.net/oskar/zwFeV/

Comment: Ok,I changed to each but it`s just hiding the list and don`t slide them.
This is the new code :       visibleSubMenus.each(function(el) {
          var slider = new Fx.Slide(el, {
              duration: 2000
          });
          slider.slideOut();
      });

Comment: Ok,this is not working because the li`s have position:absolute,how can i fix it?

Comment: Yes it is working, obviously the height of the `ul` needs to be fixed at a specific value. This is the price you have to pay when playing with positioning. Refresh the example link to see the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

The `$$()` function in Mootools is mostly equivalent to JQuery's `$()` does-it-all selector.

```
// in MooTools
var elements = $$('.someSelector');

// natively in most newer browsers
elements = document.body.querySelectorAll('.someSelector');
```

However, for this specific case since :visible isn't a real pseudo class, you'll have to approximate it using an Array filter in Mootools.

```
var isItemVisible = function (item) {
    return item.style.visibility != 'hidden' && item.style.display != 'none';
}
var elements = $$('ul').filter(isItemVisible);
```

There might be other things that you consider make an item 'invisible', in which case you can add them to the filtering function accordingly.

Comment: I will change my questions - How I can get all the visible ul on my page?In jQuery I can use 'ul:visible'.

Comment: I put up an edit that will work for your case. :visible isn't a standard pseudo-class so you have to be creative in Mootools.